# WordPress: Public web content entries and Private JSON content?

Tags: json, wordpress, ios, private, feed

We have a client that is using WordPress as a website CMS.

They want to do the following:

- Publish 2 types of entries (public and private)
- Public entries are available on the web as normal
- Private entries are only available via a private URL JSON feed which will be retrieved via in-app purchasing in an iPad app

How can this public/private scenario be accomplished with WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe these 2 URLs supply me with everything I need:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Visibility

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/

Comment: what request do you send in order to get the private entries.
Do I need to make a login using the json api ?